# How to automatically refresh the page after submitting a form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an HTML form, where, when I click "update" the changes do not reflect and it requires a refresh to see the changes.
But when I reload, there's always `Confirm Form Resubmission`.

I used `<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">` which means it submits on the same page.

Comment: Please include samples of your HTML form so that we can see any mistakes you may have made

Comment: If you need simple refresh you can use html meta refresh

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` should not be used to encode paths. It is for encoding output.

Comment: There is no reason to use: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` here. Especially with htmlspecialchars. Just leave the action empty. This doesn't answer the question **How to automatically refresh the page after submitting a form** but leaving the action empty would result in the exact same thing you were trying to do (which is wrong).

Answer (score 5):

You can refresh the page in multiple way :

**Way : 1**

```
if(isset($_POST[submits])) {
    header("location:index.php"); // your current page
}
```

**Way : 2**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Your SQL Query
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>";
}
```

**Way : 3** (not recommended)

`onsubmit="window.location.reload();"` it seems this does not work. So i use the timeout function in it. To make it work.

```
onsubmit="setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(); }, 5)"
```

**Way : 4**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

Comment: I can't figure out where I'm supposed to put the first code block

Comment: That doesn't work in October. Not your fault, though, I decided to abandon PHP entirely.

Comment: @siddharth you can use the timeout function. Like `onsubmit="setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload();},5)"`. Increase the time as per your needs, to submit the form & then reload it to the page. I have updated the methods & added some more methods.

Answer (score 1):

So the main issue with what you are describing is that the url request method is POST. If you refresh the page after submitting the form the browser will attempt to POST again, just as if you hit the submit button.

This is actually a very natural way to submit data (to the url the form is generated on). Most open source CMSs will do the same thing and have the same behavior (wordpress, drupal).

I built a custom system that did the same thing but had some complaints about refresh triggering the "Are you sure you want to submit this form again" instead of just reloading the form. So I solve the issue with @Bruce s solution. At the bottom of my page before I output anything I do a redirect to the current url. This changes the previous page in the browsers eyes to a GET instead of the POST and prevents the re-submission warning.

As for your data not updating you are probably building your form before processing the post. Make sure processing the post is the first operation you perform.

My system is very different than this example code so don't expect this to work out of the box. But it should give you the right idea.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) && ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"))
{
  // Validate my form.
  if ($valid)
  { 
    // Save data on successful validation.

    // Redirect to prevent refresh from triggering another
    // form submission. Optional but helpful.
    redirect($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  }
  else
  {
    // Not valid no harm in just reloading as the user will be
    // fixing their errors and resubmitting anyway.

    // Generate error messages, etc.
  }
}

// Retrieve your form values here after you have fully processed the POST
// operation.
$values = getDBValues();    

function redirect($path)
{
   // The path should be validated somehow as the user
   // could alter parts of it such as query parameters.
   // For simplicity I'm leaving that part out.
   header('Location: ' . $path);
   die();
}

?>
<html>
<form>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use AJAX form submissions:

```
// Bind the submit action
$('#myForm').submit(mySubmitFunction);

// Submit handler
function mySubmitFunction(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);

    $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function(xhr) {
            // My endpoint returns JSON output
            var responseJSON = false;
            try {
                    responseJSON = $.parseJSON(xhr);
            } catch (error) {}

            if (responseJSON && responseJSON.hasOwnProperty('result') &&
                responseJSON.result) {
                    // The important bit
                    location.reload();
            } else {
                    // Handle error
            }
    });
}
```

I chose for this in order to be able to provide quick feedback to the user. If you don't want to use AJAX, a simple header('Location: yourPage.php') in the PHP file processing your form will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Your page already reloads after "update", because `Confirm Form Resubmission` alert pops. I guess the problem is that in php script you display data before processing new Post data.